# Filter json object array with grep

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter a json array with jquery grep, but the grep doesn't return the right output.

```
var response = "[{"ID":1,"Name":"Test1","Active":true},
{"ID":2,"Name":"Test2","Active":false},
{"ID":3,"Name":"Test3","Active":true}]";

var onlyActive =  $.grep(response, function (value) {
            return value.Active = true;
        });
```

Comment: use === instead of  = its assigment operator

Comment: Alll you need to do is add == comparison instead of = true ;

Comment: or just `return value.Active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code that i see:

First: 
There is an extra leading " in your JSON object. Should be:-

```
var response = [
    {"ID":1,"Name":"Test1","Active":true},
    {"ID":2,"Name":"Test2","Active":false},
    {"ID":3,"Name":"Test3","Active":true}
];
```

Second: 
You are returning an assignment `value.Active = true` which is incorrect. It should be:-

```
var onlyActive =  $.grep(response, function (value) {
    return value.Active;
});
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you . My string is with double quotes and doesn't work . How can I remove the double quotes;

Comment: @Lio [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)